# Не удается получить Spinner для menu android, getActionView() возвращает null

Tags: android, menu

Делаю выпадающее меню spinner для некоторых пунктов меню NavigationDrawer. 
Почему не удается получить переменную spinner, оба способа возвращают null?

```
   NavigationView nav_draw = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   Menu menu =  nav_draw.getMenu();
   MenuItem item =  menu.findItem(R.id.nav_myflat);
   1) Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();

   2) View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
   View v = myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
   Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v;
```

Вот мой activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
                android:transitionName="actionBar" />


        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:openDrawer="start">

            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
            />

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
                      />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

main_menu.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group
                android:id="@+id/group1"
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
               <item android:id="@+id/nav_uprav"
                  android:title="@string/drawer_item_uprav" >
                <menu>
                    <item android:id="@+id/nav_news"
                          android:title="@string/drawer_item_news" />
                    <item android:id="@+id/nav_obiav"
                          android:title="@string/drawer_item_obiav" />
                    <item android:id="@+id/submenu3"
                          android:title="SubMenu 3" />
                </menu>
            </item>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_myflat"
                  android:title="@string/drawer_item_myflat" >
                  app:actionLayout="@layout/spinner"/>
                <menu>
                    <item android:id="@+id/nav_auth"
                          android:title="@string/drawer_item_auth" />
                    <item android:id="@+id/nav_video"
                          android:title="@string/drawer_item_video" />
                    <item android:id="@+id/submenu5"
                          android:title="SubMenu 6" />
                </menu>
            </item>
        </group>
</menu>
```

spinner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/spinner"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
         android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Comment: У вас спиннер будет **в итеме** или **итемом**? Иными словами, вам нужен список-дерево? Как в Google Play?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на пункт меню раскрывались еще пункты. я подумала что надо спиннер к item прикрутить к тому который должен раскрываться. Может я не так делаю? подскажите тогда как надо пож)

Comment: та библиотека что посоветовал drugs_and_code подошла бы, я думала спиннер так же будет выглядеть

Comment: Спиннер в айтеме будет открываться **над**, а не под айтемом. Поэтому та библиотека вполне хороша, но я бы использовал MaterialDrawer, это и боковое меню и список всякого типа айтемов в одной библиотеке вообще без xml

Comment: ага ясно, тогда куда же его ставить надо, группу создать под айтемом и туда его?

Comment: Вообще не нужен спиннер, все решается в библиотеке скрытием/показом айтемов. Не знаю как в той, что предложили ниже, так как использую MaterialDrawer

Comment: ясно, спасибо, похоже придется бросить спиннер)

Comment: Да да) Можете смело стирать весь код и меню и в xml и в java и переходить на эту либу > https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Comment: @Flippy у вас есть пример выпадающего меню на этой библиотеке? не получается ее установить. Ей нужен API 25?

Comment: Ответ дал. Нет, библиотека работает с API 14. Что именно не получается установить? Я ее использую в текущем проекте, вот build.gradle > https://github.com/D330/Skyscrapers/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: Я так поняла что мин API 14 это да, но ему нужно  compileSdkVersion 25,  targetSdkVersion 25 потому что не получается в градле вот это подключить: compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
            transitive = true
        } ,  требуюет еще библиотеки которые для API 25

Comment: А в skyscrapers вообще в градле compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: Ну тогда установить 25 (а лучше 26) SDK

Comment: мне нужно чтобы приложение поддерживалось большинством телефонов, поэтому лучше чтобы min API было 14, а с SDK 25 min API идет уже только 16 самое меньшее. Просто странно что у mikepenz в описании написано что работает с min 14 а на самом деле это не так..

Comment: Вы даже меня запутали)

Answer (score 1):

Для выпадающих пунктов меню попробую использовать вот эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/msahakyan/expandable-navigation-drawer)

мне она помогла с этой задачей.

Comment: Спасибо, да хорошая библитека, если не получится со спинером то попробую. Столько времени уже на него потратила( жалко бросать

Answer (score 0):

С библиотекой `MaterialDrawer` можно сделать так:

**Раскрывающийся пункт меню "Категории" с подпунктами "Игры" и "Фильмы"**

```
PrimaryDrawerItem sub_category_games = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
    .withName("Игры")
    .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_games);
PrimaryDrawerItem sub_category_films = new PrimaryDrawerItem()
    .withName("Фильмы")
    .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_films);
ExpandableDrawerItem category_expandable_item = new ExpandableDrawerItem()
    .withName("Категории")
    .withSelectable(false)
    .withSubItems(sub_category_games, sub_category_films)
    .withIcon(R.drawable.ic_category);
Drawer drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withToolbar(toolbar)
    .addDrawerItem(category_expandable_item)
    .build();
```